# Get percentage of selected words in a large corpus in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I have a list of keywords like the following:

```
keywords = {'dog', 'people', 'bird', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'forest'}
```

I would like to get the percentage of times all of these words appear in each row of a column in a pandas dataframe. Each row in the column contains a lot of texts. With the following code, I get the count of the selected keywords in the column named `perc_words`. Is there any way to transform this into a percentage? Thanks much.

```
import pandas as pd
df['perc_words'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: sum(i in keywords for i in str(x).split()))
```

Comment: Could you upload an example of what `df` is supposed to be? Is it a simple dictionary? Also, is it insufficient to simply divide the counts of the words by the total number of words?

Comment: Hi @Seankala the ```df['text']``` column represents many processed texts in each row. In other words, each row contains one text file which is lower-cased and stopwords-removed. You are right, dividing the counts by the total number of words would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.str.count()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to count the occurrences of `keywords`, then divide by [**`.str.len()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```py
df['perc_words'] = df.text.str.count('|'.join(keywords)) / df.text.str.split().str.len()
```

To get occurrences per 1000, you can multiply `perc_words` by 1000:

```py
df['per_1000'] = df.perc_words * 1000
```

---

Toy example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['dog apple', 'foo', 'people are people']})

#                 text
# 0          dog apple
# 1                foo
# 2  people are people
```

Count of `keywords`:

```py
df.text.str.count('|'.join(keywords))

# 0    1
# 1    0
# 2    2
# Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Count of total words:

```py
df.text.str.split().str.len()

# 0    2
# 1    1
# 2    3
# Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Percentage of `keywords`:

```py
df['perc_words'] = df.text.str.count(r'|'.join(keywords)) / df.text.str.split().str.len()
df['per_1000'] = df.perc_words * 1000

#                 text  perc_words    per_1000
# 0          dog apple    0.500000  500.000000
# 1                foo    0.000000    0.000000
# 2  people are people    0.666667  666.666667
```

Comment: Hi @tdy, thanks for the helpful answer. Is there a way to get, say, the word occurrence in every 10,000 words?

Comment: @crackers Could you explain that in more detail? Say a row has 18000 total words and it contains 500 `keywords`, what would be your desired output? You want to check the first 10,000 words, then the next 8,000 words?

Comment: Thanks for the toy example. If a row has 18000 words containing 500 ```keywords``` that means in every 18000 words, keywords occur 500 times. But how many times do keywords occur in every 1000 words?

Comment: I guess it should be if I multiply the percentage points by the desired word number, i.e., 1000?

Comment: Oh ok, if that's what you mean, yes you could say that in the first row, "dog" has a 50% occurrence rate, which would be 500 occurrences per 1000.

Comment: So you could have like `df['per_1000'] = df.perc_words * 1000`